# How to build efficient loops for element wise operations in R using map,sapply

Tags: r, performance, loops, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set with ~200k rows and I want to calculate percentile scores for multiple variables. The method that I am using takes ~10 mins for a single variable. Is there any efficient way to do this. Following is a fake data set my code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

id <- c(1:200000)
X <- rnorm(200000,mean = 5,sd=100)
DATA <- data.frame(ID =id,Var = X)

percentileCalc <- function(value){
  per_rank <- ((sum(DATA$Var < value)+(0.5*sum(DATA$Var == value)))/length(DATA$Var))
  return(per_rank)
}
```

First Method:

```
res <- numeric(length = length(DATA$Var))
sta <- Sys.time()
for (i in seq_along(DATA$Var)) {
  res[i]<-percentileCalc(DATA$Var[i])
}
sto <- Sys.time()
sto - sta
```

Output:

```
Time difference of 10.51337 mins
```

Second Method:

```
sta <- Sys.time()
res <- map(DATA$Var,percentileCalc)
sto <- Sys.time()
sto - sta
```

Output:

```
Time difference of 6.86872 mins
```

Third Method:

```
sta <- Sys.time()
res <- sapply(DATA$Var,percentileCalc)
sto <- Sys.time()
sto - sta
```

Output:

```
Time difference of 11.1495 mins
```

Next I tried a simple element wise operation but it still took time

```
simpleOperation <- function(value){
  per_rank <- sum(DATA$Var < value)
  return(per_rank)
}

res <- numeric(length = length(DATA$Var))
sta <- Sys.time()
for (i in seq_along(DATA$Var)) {
  res[i]<-simpleOperation(DATA$Var[i])
}
sto <- Sys.time()
sto - sta

Time difference of 3.369287 mins

sta <- Sys.time()
res <- map(DATA$Var,simpleOperation)
sto <- Sys.time()
sto - sta

Time difference of 3.979965 mins

sta <- Sys.time()
res <- sapply(DATA$Var,simpleOperation)
sto <- Sys.time()
sto - sta

Time difference of 6.535737 mins
```

There is percent_rank() available in dplyr which does kind of same thing, but my concern here is that even a simple operation is taking time when iterated over each element of a variable. May be I am doing something wrong.

Following is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] purrr_0.2.2 dplyr_0.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 lazyeval_0.2.0 magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.0       assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.5-1      tools_3.4.0   
[8] tibble_1.2     Rcpp_0.12.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you are implementing `(rank(DATA$Var) - 0.5) / length(DATA$Var)`.

Verification with your data and some data with not only unique values:

```
N <- 1e4
DATA <- data.frame(
  ID   = 1:N, 
  Var  = rnorm(N, mean = 5, sd = 100),
  Var2 = sample(0:10, size = N, replace = TRUE)
)

percentileCalc <- function(value) {
  (sum(DATA$Var < value) + 0.5 * sum(DATA$Var == value)) / length(DATA$Var)
}
percentileCalc2 <- function(value) {
  (sum(DATA$Var2 < value) + 0.5 * sum(DATA$Var2 == value)) / length(DATA$Var2)
}

all.equal((rank(DATA$Var) - 0.5) / length(DATA$Var),
          sapply(DATA$Var, percentileCalc))
all.equal((rank(DATA$Var2) - 0.5) / length(DATA$Var2),
          sapply(DATA$Var2, percentileCalc2))
```

---

```
simpleOperation <- function(value) {
  sum(DATA$Var < value)
}
simpleOperation2 <- function(value) {
  sum(DATA$Var2 < value)
}

all.equal(rank(DATA$Var, ties.method = "min") - 1,
          sapply(DATA$Var, simpleOperation))
all.equal(rank(DATA$Var2, ties.method = "min") - 1,
          sapply(DATA$Var2, simpleOperation2))
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some example, because it took some time for me to get why this is correct. Also you may want to specify that to get exactly the same result it is needed to divide with length of vector: `(rank(DATA$Var) - 0.5) / length(DATA$Var)`

Comment: @F. Privé rank() works for the percentile, but how to run element wise operation efficiently for other operations. For e.g. the second function I posted calculates counts of values less than the value of interest, its a very simple operation but still takes time if its to be applied on 200,000 rows. Is there any other efficient looping method or coming up with a vectorized implementation of function is the solution.